# Python: figure out what element in a for-loop is causing an issue

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am iterating over a set of Excel files with the following loop. There are over +100 files. It turns out that one of my files is missing the sheet '3. Prices' so that as expected the loop fails at a given point/file/

How can I figure out which of my 100 files is the one causing the loop to fail? (A side question would be: in what order does Python run the loop, alphabetically?)

Thanks.

```
directory = os.listdir('C:\\User\\files')

df=pd.DataFrame()    

for file in directory:
    if os.path.isfile(file):

        file_name = file[0:3]
        workbook = load_workbook(filename = file, data_only=True)
        sheet = workbook['3. Prices']
        e13 = sheet['E13'].value
        f13 = sheet['F13'].value
        g13 = sheet['G13'].value
        h13 = sheet['H13'].value
        f19 = sheet['F19'].value
        i19 = sheet['I19'].value
        k19 = sheet['K19'].value

        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({
                "File_name":file_name, 
                "E13":e13, "F13":f13, "G13":g13,"H13":h13,
                "F19":f19,"I19":i19,"K19":i19,
                }, index=[0]))
```

Comment: You can [handle your exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: What is the failure exactly? Is it an exception?

Comment: print('{}'.format(file_name)) ??

Comment: I'm not sure where you get your file list from (you don't show where `directory` comes from) but if its something like `os.listdir()` then the order is random. You can `directory.sort()` to order it.

Comment: @tdelaney, sorry about that. I now show where it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Add a try/catch around your code in print out the file name:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()    
file_name = ""
try:
    for file in directory:
        if os.path.isfile(file):

            file_name = file[0:3]
            workbook = load_workbook(filename = file, data_only=True)
            sheet = workbook['3. Prices']
            e13 = sheet['E13'].value
            f13 = sheet['F13'].value
            g13 = sheet['G13'].value
            h13 = sheet['H13'].value
            f19 = sheet['F19'].value
            i19 = sheet['I19'].value
            k19 = sheet['K19'].value

            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({
                    "File_name":file_name, 
                    "E13":e13, "F13":f13, "G13":g13,"H13":h13,
                    "F19":f19,"I19":i19,"K19":i19,
                    }, index=[0]))
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception happend in " + file_name + ". Exception: " + e)
```

Comment: It may be better to put the try/except inside the for loop so that the error can be logged and processing continue. Its also risky to catch the generic `Exception` - (that's why I asked OP for the real one so changing when that info is available would be good).